# Android webview flash problem

Tags: android, flash, webview

I want to play stream audio in webview using flash. 
I'm going to show it as possible as small.

Exception occured when setting webview size to 0*0, but not 50*50

Thread [<8> WebViewCoreThread] (Suspended (exception SecurityException))
    PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire() line: 255
    JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired() line: not available [native method]
    JWebCoreJavaBridge.fireSharedTimer() line: 88
    JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(Message) line: 105 
    JWebCoreJavaBridge(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run() line: 621
    Thread.run() line: 1096

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this permission to the app manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```